# Send row count in Subject Email

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have written SQL Server Script that sent emails. The email code is very general since we sent email to users from the SQL Server jobs that we ran. I now need to use that code to sent email to other set of users along with the row count from one the script. I am not sure how to sent the total row count in Body of the Email.

To make things more clear, say I need to sent the customer count. Hence

```
Declare @CustomerCount int
SET @CustomerCount =  (SELECT count(CustomerID) from CustomerTable)
```

Hence I need to sent an email that says

"Total Customer in database is: 1000"

Below is the stored procedure that sent email.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SQLCustomEmailProc]   
   @From varchar(100) ,  
   @To varchar(350) , /* 200 */  
   @Subject varchar(250)=" ", /* 100 */  
   @Body varchar(4000) = "Test Body"     
   AS  
   Declare @iMsg int  
   Declare @hr int  
   Declare @source varchar(255)  
   Declare @description varchar(500)  
   Declare @output varchar(1000)  

--************* Create the CDO.Message Object ************************  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'CDO.Message', @iMsg OUT  

--***************Configuring the Message Object ******************  
-- This is to configure a remote SMTP server.  
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cdosys/html/_cdosys_schema_configuration_sendusing.asp  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing").Value','2'  
-- This is to configure the Server Name or IP address.   
-- Replace MailServerName by the name or IP of your SMTP Server.  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver").Value', 'smtp.mycompany.com'   

-- Save the configurations to the message object.  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Configuration.Fields.Update', null  

-- Set the e-mail parameters.  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'To', @To  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'From', @From  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Subject', @Subject  

-- If you are using HTML e-mail, use 'HTMLBody' instead of 'TextBody'.  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'TextBody', @Body  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Send', NULL  

-- Sample error handling.  
   IF @hr <>0   
     select @hr  
     BEGIN  
       EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetErrorInfo NULL, @source OUT, @description OUT  
       IF @hr = 0  
         BEGIN  
           SELECT @output = '  Source: ' + @source  
           PRINT  @output  
           SELECT @output = '  Description: ' + @description  
           PRINT  @output  
         END  
       ELSE  
         BEGIN  
           PRINT '  sp_OAGetErrorInfo failed.'  
           RETURN  
         END  
     END  

-- Do some error handling after each step if you need to.  
-- Clean up the objects created.  
   EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @iMsg  

   PRINT 'Mail has been sent!'
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL are you running?  If you have 2008+ and a database mail profile set up just use [sp_send_dbmail:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

```
Declare @CustomerCount int
Declare @mailBody varchar(255)

SET @CustomerCount =  (SELECT count(CustomerID) from CustomerTable)
set @mailBody = 'Total Customer in database is: ' + @CustomerCount
Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients='Person@company.com',
@subject='Total Customers Count',
@body=@mailBody
```